# button thumbnail slider effect unity3D

Tags: unity, c#, gui

[image]

I am trying to make this effect for buttons. i.e the middle one is bigger and is selected. the buttons can be moved left or right by swapping with finger. Does anyone have any idea how to do it?

Comment: This looks like a common UI control called a carousel, or sometimes "cover flow". There are [lots of existing assets](https://www.google.com/search?q=unity+carousel+asset) to provide this out of the box, and [tutorials about creating this kind of interface](https://www.google.com/search?q=unity+carousel+tutorial). What have you tried based on your research of this wealth of information so far?

Comment: Ok I found a slider asset. but it was simple image movement left or right. I will try this out.

Comment: I followed a tutorial and I was able to create this effect

Comment: Great, want to post your solution as an Answer below to help others?

Comment: Okay. But really thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

I found this tutorial link with the help of DMGregory. 
[Click here for the tutorial project](https://sushanta1991.blogspot.com/2016/12/how-to-create-carousel-view-with-unity.html)

All you have to do is add panels as

```
-main
    ->child
        ->grandChild
            ->emptyObject
                ->button1
                ->button2...
```

add script `CreateProfile` to child. and the the buttons and emptyObject to it. And thats it.